# Order datastore entities on a list property of name/value object with objectify

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Using the Google Cloud Datastore, I want to list my entities.
I want to retrieve them ordered by the value of a property depending of its name.

Java class model:

```
public class ContainerEntity {
    @Index
    String id;
    @Index
    private List<NameValueProperty> properties;
}

public class NameValueProperty {
    @Index
    private String name;
    @Index
    private String value;
}
```

Data set example:

```
"items": [
{
   "id": "114191058616700893306-20180416-120212-125-Qotx9AlsSRHg4cJhya",
   "properties": [
    {
     "name": "propertyIWantToOrderBy",
     "value": "BBBB"
    },
    {
     "name": "propertyIDoNotCareTheOrder",
     "value": "1522540800000"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "114191058616700893306-20180416-120718-199-Qotx9AlsSRHg4cJhya",
   "properties": [
    {
     "name": "propertyIWantToOrderBy",
     "value": "AAAA"
    },
    {
     "name": "propertyIDoNotCareTheOrder",
     "value": "1522540800000"
    }
   ]
  }
}
```

How can I do that using objectify?
I tried using this snippet of code but it does not work:

```
Query<ContainerEntity> query = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(ContainerEntity.class);
query = query.filter("properties.name = ", "propertyIWantToOrderBy")
             .order("properties.value");
```

First it filters (which I don't want), and then it looks like it's not correctly order on the property with the name "propertyIWantToOrderBy". Is there any solution/workaround to do that? Would like to do something like order("properties.value where properties.name='propertyIWantToOrderBy'"). **The main point of this design is to have a dynamic entity**.

Objectify version: 5.1.22
Jdk: 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List properties can be confusing when you try to filter and order them. Try this approach instead:

```
public class ContainerEntity {
    @Id
    String id;
    @Index
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Now your query looks like this:

```
ofy().load().type(ContainerEntity.class).order("properties.propertyIWantToOrderBy");
```

BTW you don't `@Index` ids, which are not stored as regular properties. They need the `@Id` annotation.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I implemented it at the end. Thanks!